# Mage::log() will work for writing to system.log (sometimes) but not a custom file

Tags: magento-1.9, log

I have a cronjob for Magento 1.9 running to test some functions, so naturally I want to log the results of these functions, and make sure they're running. Initially, I had the line `Mage::log('Running function');` and then another log line to write the variable. And this worked, but with all my testing, it was cluttering `system.log` so I decided to have it write all of this to a file called `test.log` instead. I changed that line to `Mage::log('Running function', null, 'test.log');` but now no logs are being written. I even tried creating an empty `test.log` file manually but it isn't being populated. That is the only line I changed.* All my files have 777 permissions set and are owned by www-data (I am on Ubuntu). My logging is enabled (it was just logging to `system.log` so this is obvious). What could the issue be?

*Edit: I found that it wasn't the only line I changed. I had added a variable declaration (for a variable that wasn't even being used, so I didn't think it would affect my code) and I think magento didn't like that line. Shouldn't this have gone into a log file somewhere though?

Answer (score 0):

Try to launch in your magento directory :

`sudo find . -type f -exec chmod 400 {} \; && sudo find . -type d -exec chmod 500 {} \; && sudo find var/ -type f -exec chmod 600 {} \; && sudo find media/ -type f -exec chmod 600 {} \; && sudo find var/ -type d -exec chmod 700 {} \; && sudo find media/ -type d -exec chmod 700 {} \; && sudo chmod 700 includes && sudo chmod 600 includes/config.php`

It will fix perm like [Magento documentation](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/m1x/install/installer-privileges_after.html#privs-after).

Comment: No, I already have permissions at 777 for now, while I'm developing. I'm not going to change it to stricter rules. But I think I figured out the issue anyways, I had an extra line in there that shouldn't have been affecting any of my code, but magento didn't like it, so it was stopping there and never getting to the log lines.

Answer (score 0):

`system.log` : is used for all **Php Warning**, **XML-file** contains errors and warnings.

`exception.log` : is for all Exceptions when Magento not be able to detect the correct data then it log that in exception.log.

So log this two files and you custom log file. `tail -f system.log exception.log test.log`

Comment: There is no `exception.log` file. Why might that be? Because I found that I had added a line that magento didn't like, but it was failing silently and not logging anything, rather than logging that it hit an error.

Comment: Go to `Admin>system>Configuration>Developper>Log settings>` then  `Enable the first field`, Second : `system.log`, Third : `exception.log`.

Comment: Thanks but it's already like that. I just double checked to make sure, but logging is enabled and `system.log` and `exception.log` are both in the other fields. And it's not permissions because the entire var folder (the entire magento directory actually) has 777 permission.